# Java mysql query ("SELECT * FROM movies" is only returning 1 row

Tags: java, mysql

I´m doing a simple movie-renting application, and this method from the `DAO` section is supposed to return an array of "movie" objects, but only returns 1 movie.

I checked the database, connection is fine, but only list the first row and nothing else. There are currently 3 movies entries on the database.

```
public ArrayList<Pelicula> obtainMovies () {

    ArrayList<Movie> p=new ArrayList<>();
    Movie pelic=new Movie();

    try{
        conn=connect();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM movies";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            pelic.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            pelic.setGenre(rs.getString("genre"));
            pelic.setRating(rs.getInt("rating"));
            pelic.setRented(rs.getBoolean("rented"));
            p.add(pelic);
        }
        else {return null;}

        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table has more then one row, this

```
if(rs.next()){
```

should use a loop like

```
while(rs.next()){
```

Also, you'll need to add more then one instance to your `List`, so move `pelic` into the loop body

```
while(rs.next()){
  Movie pelic=new Movie();
```

Or you'll add only one instance of `Movie` to the `List` (and modify that single instance with each loop iteration).

Comment: Many, many thanks! That worked like a charm. I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(rs.next()){
```

You probably want to loop over all results:

```
 while(rs.next()){
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! The first reply did the job.